# How can i see all users who have logged in to my computer (and when recently?) Via cmd command and by registry

Tags: cmd, registry

I would love to get help on how can I see all users who have logged in to my computer (and when recently?) Via cmd command and by registry.

Comment: Maybe the `net user` command can help you.

Comment: To see them all, you'll need a webcam! _If all else fails, try asking them, `Set /P "Name=Please enter your name"`, then write `%Name%` to a location you can read it from_. Your question is off topic, we do not do your research for you, we help you to fix your provided code, after you've researched it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a supported Windows system, PowerShell is available. Using it to see logged in users on another computer will require that PowerShell Remoting be competently configred.

=== Get-LoggedOnUsers.ps1

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
    [string[]]$ComputerName = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostName()
)
foreach ($Computer in $ComputerName) {
    ((Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_LoggedOnUser -ComputerName $Computer).Antecedent |
        Sort-Object -Unique) |
        ForEach-Object { "$($_.domain)\$($_.name)" }
}
```

Run it with:

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -File ".\Get-LoggedOnUsers.ps1"
```